# Twitter sentiment - free existing tool?

Tags: twitter, sentiment-analysis

I need a tool to analyze tweets sentiment (positive/neutral/negative). I would like it to be free for students.

So far I found **Sentiment140** (http://www.sentiment140.com/) and **Sanders-Twitter Sentiment Corpus** (http://www.sananalytics.com/lab/twitter-sentiment/). Although both tools provides only training data (I know, I can use them with NLTK (http://nltk.org/)).

But I would like to know if there is any python script or a Java program, that is free distributed and can be download and run to analyze tweets sentiment. I need to analyze huge set of data, so using Sentiment140 REST API is also unsatisfying.

Any ideas?

PS. I'm interested in english sentiment analyse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TextBlob](https://textblob.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), a python package to analyze short texts for sentiment offline. There is a trained model included with the package, so you won't need to train one. It should be fine for some projects, but if you want to achieve greater accuracy, consider training your own model on your specific data.